# Given 2 columns (A,B), how to filter column B based on values in column A?

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that looks similar to the table below:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Null | Null |
| Null | Null |
| To | John Doe |
| CC | Jane Doe |
| To | Null |
| CC | Null |

I want to filter the table so that rows that have a value in A but Null in B do not show, similar to table below:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Null | Null |
| Null | Null |
| To | John Doe |
| CC | Jane Doe |

Comment: is the `Null` a true blank cell or does it show the word `Null` in the cell?

Comment: Shows the word Null

Comment: I assume you want to use the autofilter?  Or are you after the FILTER() formula in Office 365?  Or are you wanting vba?

Comment: I was after the FILTER() formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=FILTER(A1:B6,NOT((A1:A6<>"Null")*(B1:B6="Null")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm I'm getting a #SPILL! error

Comment: @Gio then you have items in the cells below or to the side where excel wants to spill the results.  The cells into which the data will spill need to be blank.  You would only put this formula in the upper left cell of the output range and it will be filled automatically. See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-spill-error-ffe0f555-b479-4a17-a6e2-ef9cc9ad4023

Comment: I was able to sort out the spill error, thank you!